# Remove elements (and change size) of std::vector without affecting allocated memory

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

I'm using code such as the following:

```
const int MY_SIZE = 100000;
std::vector<double> v;
v.reserve(MY_SIZE);

// add no more than MY_SIZE elements to the vector

f(v);    
v.clear();

// again, add no more than MY_SIZE elements to the vector

f(v);
v.clear();

//
// etc...
//
```

The point of my code is to store `MY_SIZE` `double`'s and then perform an operation `f(std::vector<double>)` on those elements.  After I fill up the vector and perform the operation, I want to get rid of all the elements (and reset `std::vector::size()` to 0), and then add more elements.  But, the key here is that I do **not** want to cause the space in memory allocated for the vector to be changed.

Note than I'm never going to add more than `MY_SIZE` elements to `v`, so `v` should never need to reallocate more memory than was allocated by `v.reserve(MY_SIZE)`.

So, when I call `v.clear()` in the above code, will it affect in any way the amount of space allocated by `v.reserve(MY_SIZE)` or the location in memory of `v.begin()`?

---

**Related question**:  If I call `v.erase(v.begin(),v.begin()+v.size())`, will it affect in any way the amount of space allocated by `v.reserve(MY_SIZE)` or the location in memory of `v.begin()`?

If I really just wanted to erase all the elements, I would call `clear()`.  But I'm wondering about this related question because there are occasions when I need to erase only the first X elements of `v`, and on these occasions I want to keep the memory allocated by `v.reserve(MY_SIZE)` and I don't want the location of `v` to change.

Comment: No. Clear does not reallocate. You can check `capacity()` to see it hasn't changed.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was thinking, but wasn't certain from looking up `std::vector::clear()`.  I'm sure the answer to this question (indirectly, if not directly) exists in the language documentation, but from what I looked at, I couldn't be certain.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Are you sure about that? AFAIK most implementations do not change the capacity. However, it is allowed by the standard to shrink it.

Comment: @nosid, I find that very surprising, but you may be right.

Comment: @nosid, see [LWG 1102](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#1102) which was closed as Not A Defect because the standard already (apparently) guarantees that erasing elements doesn't change `capacity()`

Comment: @JonathanWakely so I guess "erasures" would include both the discarding of elements in `clear()` and in `erase(...)`.

Comment: @synaptik, yes, just as "insertions" includes `push_back`

Comment: If you don't need dynamic array expansion, you may just use an ordinary array/pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the C++ standard (2003) implicitly guarantees that the memory is not reallocated if you call the `clear()` or `erase()` method of the `std::vector`.

According to the requirements of the Sequence (table 67) the `a.clear()` is equivalent to `a.erase(begin(),end())`.

Furthermore, the standard states that the `erase(...)` member function of the `std::vector<T>` does not throw an exception unless one is thrown by the copy constructor of T (section 23.2.4.3). Hence it is implicitly guaranteed, because a reallocation could cause an exception (sections 3.7.3, 20.4.1.1).

Also `v.begin()` remains the same, as `erase(...)` will only invalidate all iterators after the point of the erase (section 23.2.4.3). However, it won't be dereferenceable (since `v.begin() == v.end()`).

So, if you have a standard compliant implementation you are fine...

**CORRECTION**

My reasoning is flawed. I managed to show that `erase(...)` does not reallocate, but an implementation could still deallocate the memory if you erase all elements. However, if `a.capacity()` reports "you can add N elements without reallocating memory" after the erase/clear you are fine.

The C++11 standard defines `a.clear()` without referring to `a.erase(...)`. `a.clear()` is not allowed to throw an exception. Hence it could deallocate, but not reallocate. So you should check the capacity after clearing the vector to make sure that the memory is still there and the next resize won't reallocate.